# Is there a way to only test 1 group against all other groups in R?

Tags: r, p-value

I have a data set with multiple populations measured across time. There are 3 separate groups of patients in the data set:

- Healthy controls measured at 1 time point (HC)
- patient group 1 measured at 6 time points (P1)
- patient group 2 measured at 6 time points (P2)

I want to test all of the patients at each time point against the healthy control group only and do p-value adjustment accordingly. I am unsure how I can code this on R.

Currently what I have done is to split my data table into 2 - 1 with HC and P1 group only (data_1) and then another with HC and P2 group only (data_2). Then I've done the wilcoxon's tests and p-value adjustments separately but this of course is not completely correct. Below is my code that uses the rstatix package

```
 data_1 %>%
          group_by(Time) %>%
          wilcox_test(data =, Population1 ~ Group, paired = FALSE) %>%
          adjust_pvalue(method = "fdr") %>%
          add_significance("p.adj")
```

Is there a way I can do the testing of HC against both groups but not the groups against each other and adjust the pvalues without having to separate my data table into 2?

I would like to be able to easily change the population1 into any of the other populations I want to do the test for so the above code works best for me when comparing the two patient groups against each other but it's not the best for comparing the HC against all the other groups.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of *data_1* and ideally an expected output. Otherwise its difficult to come up with a good solution.

Comment: The usual way to compare a control against treatments is to use the Dunnett test assuming that you have normally distributed data, or Dunn's test for nonparametric testing. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416577/changing-control-group-for-dunnett-glht-in-multcomp  However, what is your justification for comparing at *every* time point? What if you get a signif result at time=3 and 5 and non-signif at time=1,2,4,6? Adjusting alpha by FDR as you have it is great, but will your results be interpretable? Do you have access to a statistician?